# Display Image In Android Studio On Device Connected Externally

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

I am new to Android Learning. I am trying to make a `customAdapter` that will display an image and a text in every row. In my `Main_Activity`, I have following code:`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String [] foods= {"Biryani","Matar Qeema","Chicken"};
    ListAdapter faizisAdapter= new CustomAdapter(this,foods);
    ListView faizisListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.faizisListView);
    faizisListView.setAdapter(faizisAdapter);
    faizisListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String food= String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,food,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is my `CustomAdapter`:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    CustomAdapter(Context context, String []foods)
    {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row, foods);
    }

public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater faisizInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View faizisView = faisizInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, 
false);
    String food = getItem(position);

    TextView _foodsDisplay = (TextView) 
faizisView.findViewById(R.id._foodDisplay);
    ImageView _imageDisplay = (ImageView) 
faizisView.findViewById(R.id._imageDisplay);

    _imageDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.zaheer8423);
    _foodsDisplay.setText(food);
    return faizisView;
    }
}
```

My `Main_Activity_XML_FILE` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/faizisListView"
    >
</ListView>
```

`XML_FILE_FOR_customAdapter`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/_imageDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/zaheer8423"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/_foodDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I haved saved image file in `app/src/main/res/drawable/zaheer8423.jpg`. I have connected my android device with android studio externally. When I run the app It opens and suddenly closes.

I have seen ways that use bitmap but I could not use them effectively, because I have very little knowledge about them.

Please help me here.

Comment: try to move your image in drawable-xxhdpi,may be the size of image is too big

Comment: try logcat selet eror and check what is the error your app is getting crashed

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :)

Comment: Could you please help me draw image in circular shape?

Comment: use this library for circular image https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView, include the library in app.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Image size is big,You might need to scale down image something like this.

```
      // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        option.inSampleSize = scale;
        //You need to calculate appropriate sample size 
        Bitmap bitmap =  



BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.zaheer8423,option);
imageDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

As its adapter you need to manage caching the bitmap and creating bitmap should be done in worker thread (Non Main thread i.e. UI Thread ) to avoid ANRs.